# Python, how to create a iterable with the same type as a random iterable

Tags: python, types, iterable, flatten

I'm trying to create a function that flattens a nested combination and delivers it in a iterable that has the same type as the input. So for example:

```
>>> # tuple with list, tuple and set
￼>>> flatten_iterable([[1,2,3],(1,2,3),{1,2,3}])
￼[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
￼>>> # set with tuples
￼>>> flatten_iterable({(1,2,3),(3,4,5),(5,6,7,8)})
￼{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
￼>>> # tuple with list, set, tuple
￼>>> flatten_iterable(([1,2,3],{3,4,5},(5,6,7,8)))
￼(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8)
￼
```

So far I have the following code:

```
def flatten_iterable(a_list):
    new_list = []
    import collections
    for i in a_list:
        if isinstance(i, collections.Iterable):
            new_list.extend(flatten_iterable(i))
        else:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list
```

But I just don't know how I can make the `new_list` to have the same type as the input.

Comment: What if the input is another iterable, for example function that yields values? What will you return in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def _flatten_helper(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        if isinstance(item, Iterable):
            yield from _flatten_helper(item)
        else:
            yield item

def flatten_iterable(iterable):
    return type(iterable)(_flatten_helper(iterable))

flatten_iterable([[1,2,3],(1,2,3),{1,2,3}])
# [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

This works for input iterables that accept an iterable as an argument. We get the type of the input iterable, then call that with a generator of the flattened iterable.  (More properly, I think this only works for `Collection`s)

Answer (score 1):

This one should do:

```
def flatten_iterable(a_list):
    return type(a_list)([i for sub in a_list for i in sub])
```